# Does binding a container instance to a different number of cores have an impact on performance given a fixed CPU quota?

Tags: multithreading, performance, multiprocessing, containers

In container environments, it's possible to control the CPU quota allocated to an instance, as well as the specific logical core IDs it can utilize. Regarding typical multi-threaded network service applications, **does allocating more available logical cores affect the service's throughput or latency?** （Not considering the impact of hyper threading conflicts）

For instance, in a scenario where an instance runs 16 independent threads and is allocated a CPU quota for 8 cores (800% cpu.util), would binding it to CPU 0-7, CPU 0-15, or CPU 0-31 impact performance?

**If there is an effect, what trends might we observe, and which variables could this be related to?**

Comment: AFAIK you cannot control the quota in the container but outside it and generally with additional rights (e.g. root). Moreover, if you try to bind a thread to a core/hw-thread the container do not own, then it cannot be scheduled on it and the behaviour should be similar to scheduling threads on cores you do not physically have (i.e. binding errors and non-constrained scheduling). This is certainly dependent of the configuration of the container.

Comment: the latency and throughput are AFAIK more dependent of the application than the number of cores allocated to a container. If the application can use (and actually do use) the cores, then yes, otherwise, at the OS level, this just impacts the scheduling (more cores tends to cause less context switches but possibly more cache-misses regarding the actual specific use-case). Note that the physical numbering is dependent of the hardware and few other parameters (sometime IDs are interleaved and sometimes not). `hwloc-ls` helps to know that (especially on Linux).

Comment: @JérômeRichard The control of container quota and the configuration of binding cores are carried out outside the container, and there will be no binding errors (the container can run on the host logical core assigned to it). Can there be a reliable analysis method for the impact of CPU core count on service throughput from the perspectives of queuing theory and/or process scheduling, without considering micro-architecture aspect such as cache-miss?